# Laravel 7 - belongsTo relation - Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent, relation

**Before I start**: I already read the "Similar questions" suggestions, and although there are indeed many similar questions with problem like mine, I haven't find the solutions yet. I also only started to learn Laravel for a few days, so please bear with me.

I'm using the latest Laravel framework (7.18.0). I have three tables:

```
pirates
----------
pirate_id serial NOT NULL, -- PK
pirate_name character varying(200) NOT NULL,
beard_size integer NOT NULL,
beard_color integer NOT NULL,

beard_sizes
----------
beard_size_id serial NOT NULL, -- PK
beard_size character varying(100) NOT NULL

beard_colors
----------
beard_color_id serial NOT NULL, -- PK
beard_color character varying(100) NOT NULL
```

I generated the model with php artisan command and tried to define the models:

**Pirate.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Pirate extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    
    protected $primaryKey = 'pirate_id';
    
    protected $fillable = ['pirate_name', 'beard_size', 'beard_color'];
    
    public function beardSize()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\BeardSize', 'beard_size_id');
    }
    
    public function beardColor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\BeardColor', 'beard_color_id');
    }
}
```

**BeardSize.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BeardSize extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    
    protected $primaryKey = 'beard_size_id';
    
    protected $fillable = ['beard_size'];
    
    public function pirates()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Pirate', 'pirate_id');
    }
}
```

**BeardColor.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BeardColor extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    
    protected $primaryKey = 'beard_color_id';
    
    protected $fillable = ['beard_color'];
    
    public function pirates()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Pirate', 'pirate_id');
    }
}
```

Tried to display my "pirates" table's data, this is my controller:

**PirateController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Pirate;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class PirateController extends Controller
{
    public function main()
    {
        $pirates = Pirate::paginate(4);
        
        return view('main', ['pirates' => $pirates]);
    }
}
```

and here is my view:

**main.blade.php**

```
@extends('pirate')

@section('main_nav', 'This is our ship')

@section('main_content')

<p>List of our crew:</p>

<table class="table-view">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 60px;">No.</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th style="width: 160px;">Beard size</th>
            <th style="width: 160px;">Beard color</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($pirates as $ind => $pirate)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ ($ind + 1) . '.' }}</td>
            <td>{{ $pirate->pirate_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $pirate->beardSize->beard_size }}</td>
            <td>{{ $pirate->beardColor->beard_color }}</td>
            <td class="table-nav"><a href="update/{{$pirate->pirate_id}}">edit</a></td>
            <td class="table-nav"><a href="delete/{{$pirate->pirate_id}}">delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>

{{ $pirates->links() }}

@endsection
```

Every time I tried to get the relation table's data (`beard_sizes` and `beard_colors`), I got errors either: `Trying to get property 'beard_size' of non-object` or `Trying to get property 'beard_color' of non-object`. For the record, the `beard_size` and `beard_color` column in `pirates` table are not null.

Regarding the field names in the database tables, the documentation mentioned how primary key should be written with `id`, etc., however in my next project, I'm using an already existing database with 100+ tables, so changing the name of the columns is impossible.

Comment: see your reltationship key in pirate is beard_size, but you didnt difine that in your pirate local key,

so it would be like    public function beardSize()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\BeardSize', 'beard_size_id','beard_size');
    } 
and also do the same thinks on other relation, ("mode","foreign_key", "local_key")

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I already changed the definition `public function beardSize()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\BeardSize', 'beard_size_id', 'beard_size');
    }` but the error is still there.

Comment: Can you share your migrations file with the schemas of these tables please :)

Comment: @KurtFriars sorry for the very noob question, but... How you migrate with the schemas again?

Comment: Your issue was not providing the proper key names to the belongsTo relationships. See my answer below.

Comment: The poster of the other incorrect answer downvoted my answer out of spite, please give it an upvote if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your schema you have provided you need to have the following relationships:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Pirate extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    
    protected $primaryKey = 'pirate_id';
    
    protected $fillable = ['pirate_name', 'beard_size', 'beard_color'];
    
    public function beardSize()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\BeardSize', 'beard_size', 'beard_size_id');
    }
    
    public function beardColor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\BeardColor', 'beard_color', 'beard_color_id');
    }
}
```

A belongsTo relationship has the following structure:

```
     return $this->belongsTo(Related::class, 'key_on_own_table', 'key_on_related_table');
```

Comment: I don't know why the down vote though, but your answer resolve my problem. It seems I wrote the belongsTo relation using incorrect structure. I falsely assumed the structure as: `return $this->belongsTo(Related::class, 'key_on_related_table', 'key_on_own_table')`, since the docs mentioned the 2nd parameter as foreign key and 3rd param as local key

Comment: I find relation documentation very lacking, if you ever have to customize the keys. Once you get the hang of it, its pretty straight forward.

Comment: OOT, it's funny though how I got many immediate responses here, but no answer at all at Laracast after 2 hours posting the question

Answer (score 1):

`NOT NULL` probably does not suffice for a primary key; set it to `UNSIGNED`, `BIGINT` and enable `AUTOINCREMENT`. The name of the column does not really matter. I mean, usually one can simply define it's name: `protected $primaryKey = 'pirate_id';` ...as you already have it.

<strike>And the [one-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) relationship of `App\Pirate` should be represented as:</strike>

Well, actually it's [one-to-one](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) ...as 1 pirate only has 1 beard.

```
public function beardSize()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\BeardSize', 'beard_size_id');
}

public function beardColor()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\BeardColor', 'beard_color_id');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. About the primary key, the `SERIAL` type should already implemented the `AUTOINCREMENT` attribute, no? and regarding the `Trying to get property of non-object` error, does it really affect how Laravel define relationships between models?

Comment: Postgres might have different data-types. However, this `{{ $pirate->beardSize->beard_size }}` might be the cause, because a `Pirate` only has a method `beardSize()` and not a property `beardSize`.

Comment: hasOne or hasMany is the inverse of belongsTo. Because in his/her case the beard id is being stored on the pirates table, that means pirate belongs to beard. And the beard likely has many pirates with it, so a beard has many pirates.

Comment: If one want to know how many pirates with a red beard there are, indeed. The beard itself belongs to 1 pirate, but the attributes belong to many.